# global class variable used in a spark streaming process : is it a broadcasted variable?

Tags: spark-streaming, broadcast

I just need to know if a global public class variable, used in a SparkStreaming process will be considered as a broadcasted variable.

For now, I succeeded to use a pre-setted variable "inventory" into a JavaDStream transformation.

```
class Foo {

  public static Map<String,String> inventory;

  public static void main(String args) {

    inventory = Inventory.load(); // here i set the variable

    SparkSession sparkSession = ...

    JavaStreamingContext ssc = ... // here i initialize the Spark Streaming Context

    JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> records = ...

    JavaDStream<Map<String,Object>> processedRecords = records.flatMap(rawRecord->{
      return f(rawRecord,inventory); // just an example...
    }

  }

}
```

What I understand is that the part into the lambda expression (rawRecord) is a distributed one, and then I presume that "inventory" is broadcasted to each executor that performs the process, is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global class variable is different from a broadcast variable .

> Using a class variable is fine but this can be inefficient, especially
>   for large variables such as a lookup table or a machine learning
>   model. The reason for this is that when you use a variable in a
>   closure or a class variable in your case , it must be deserialised on
>   the worker nodes many times (one per task). Moreover, if you use the
>   same variable in multiple Spark actions and jobs, it will be re-sent
>   to the workers with every job instead of once.

Broadcast variables are shared, immutable variables that
are cached on every machine in the cluster instead of serialized with every single task

All you need to do is

```
 Broadcast<Map<String,String>> broadcast = ssc.sparkContext().broadcast(inventory);
```

and access it

```
broadcast.value().get(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to broadcast that variable to keep available for all the executors in the distributed environment.